# Why does Svelte not detect changes to my reactive data?

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I am trying to update a variable on my page when it changes, but I am missing  something on Svelte reactivity. Can someone please point out what is wrong?

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/199488887cfa4de5b2257e6d9adc2ef3?version=3.48.0)

**App.svelte**

```html
<main>
    <h1>Detect data</h1>
    <p>Board number: {$room_data.board_number}</p>
</main>

<script>
    import {room_data} from './stream.js'
</script>
```

**stream.js**

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export var room_data = writable({
    board_number: -1,
});

setTimeout(function() {
    room_data.board_number = 7;
    console.log('to');
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a property of the `writable` (not its contents) here:

```js
room_data.board_number = 7;
```

You probably want to do:

```js
room_data.set({ board_number: 7 });
```

Comment: (I recommend using TypeScript, it will yell at you.)